# How to RGB blend clipped intensities and display correct blended intensity with imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

Okay, so I have a GUI, and in it I want to show color channels A and B, and the overlay C.

I want to adjust the contrast manually by simple range clipping (by basically having a intensity histogram and two vertical bars, as everybody else does it).

To display A and B I simply clip them and stuff them in `imshow`. To blend them I currently use the "screen" method, to see where spots overlap.

But the problem I have is that the blended image doesn't follow the same scaling as the clipped intensities. How should I approach this, to make sure that the blended image follows the same contrast as the single channels?

[image]

```
import skimage.exposure
import skimage.io
import skimage.data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors


def blend(image1, image2, cmap1, cmap2):
    image1_rgba = cmap1(image1)
    image2_rgba = cmap2(image2)

    return 1 - (1 - image1_rgba) * (1 - image2_rgba)

cmapgrn = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "seagreen"])
cmapred = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "red"])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 2, figsize = (10,5))
ax = ax.ravel()

multichannel = skimage.data.hubble_deep_field() # type: np.ndarray

green_raw = multichannel[:200, :200, 0]   # type: np.ndarray
red_raw   = multichannel[:200, :200, 1].T # type: np.ndarray

imgs = green_raw, red_raw

all_imgs = []
for img in imgs:
    img_rescale = img/img.max()
    all_imgs.append(img_rescale)

green, red = all_imgs # type: np.ndarray


G = green
R = red

cmin = 0.05
cmax = 0.3

ax[0].imshow(G.clip(cmin, cmax), cmap = cmapgrn)
ax[1].imshow(R.clip(cmin, cmax), cmap = cmapred)
ax[2].imshow(blend(image1 = G,
                   image2 = R,
                   cmap1 = cmapgrn,
                   cmap2 = cmapred))

ax[3].imshow(blend(image1 = G.clip(cmin, cmax),
                   image2 = R.clip(cmin, cmax),
                   cmap1 = cmapgrn,
                   cmap2 = cmapred))

ax[4].hist((G.ravel(), R.ravel()), bins = 50, color = ("green", "red"))
ax[4].axvline(cmin, color = "black")
ax[4].axvline(cmax, color = "black")

fig.delaxes(ax[5])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

So my issue was that the data was automatically matplotlib's `imshow`, thus giving the impression that it worked fully. Actually, after clipping the range, of course one needs to rescale the new values to fill out the entire range between 0 and 1 (which matplotlib does internally). The following produces correct contrast scaling:

[image]

```
import skimage.data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

cmapgrn = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "seagreen"])
cmapred = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "red"])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3, figsize = (10,5))
ax = ax.ravel()

multichannel = skimage.data.hubble_deep_field() # type: np.ndarray

green_raw = multichannel[:200, :200, 0]   # type: np.ndarray
red_raw   = multichannel[:200, :200, 1].T # type: np.ndarray

imgs = green_raw, red_raw

all_imgs = []
for img in imgs:
    img_rescale = img/img.max()
    all_imgs.append(img_rescale)

green, red = all_imgs # type: np.ndarray

G = green
R = red

cmin = 0.0
cmax = 0.5

def rescale(arr: np.ndarray):
    re = (arr - arr.min()) / (arr.max() - arr.min())
    return re


def blend(image1, image2, cmap1, cmap2):
    a = cmap1(image1)
    b = cmap2(image2)

    screen = 1 - (1 - a) * (1 - b)
    return screen


G_r = rescale(G.clip(cmin, cmax))
R_r = rescale(R.clip(cmin, cmax))

ax[0].imshow(G_r, cmap = cmapgrn)
ax[1].imshow(R_r, cmap = cmapred)
ax[2].imshow(blend(image1 = G_r,
                   image2 = R_r,
                   cmap1 = cmapgrn,
                   cmap2 = cmapred))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```